# Как выбрать n-ое наименьшее

Tags: sql

Как выбрать n-ое наименьшее, и массив с условием - если в соседнем столбце 1, тогда значение берется в массив, если 0, то нет

Comment: Если вам нужно просто из выборки показать наименьшее значение по полю то используйте aгрегатную функцию `MIN()`

Comment: нет, мне нужно не первое минимальное, а например, 7е

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос четче! От правильно заданного вопроса зависит успех решения вашей проблемы

Comment: есть массив, например:
1,2,3,4,5
Мне нужно чтобы нашлось 3-е по счету наименьшее значение. В данном случае это будет 3

Comment: а если в массиве 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - будет в ответе `3` или `2`?

Comment: 2, но в массив будет без повторов в любом случае)
В общем мне нужен аналог excelевского "наименьший"

Answer (score 1):

> n-ое наименьшее
>   Для MySQL используйте конструкцию `LIMIT`. Для других СУБД нечто аналогичное

```
SELECT val FROM myTable GROUP BY val ORDER BY val LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
```

> и массив с условием - если в соседнем столбце 1, тогда значение берется в массив, если 0, то нет

```
SELECT val FROM myTable WHERE test_col = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь функция `row_number` (или ее аналоги). Пример для sql-server:

```
WITH DT AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnName) AS Num, *
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT *
FROM  dt
WHERE Num = 7
```

Или ещё вариант (работает, начиная с sql-server 2012):

```
SELECT *
FROM  TableName
ORDER BY ColumnName
OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```